# Syntax check all stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to ensure that all stored procedures are valid.

For example, you can run the following T-SQL and it will complete:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FooBar AS

SELECT * FROM qwerr7i623487er;
```

> Commands completed successfully.

But when you execute the stored procedure at runtime, it fails:

```
EXECUTE FooBar;

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FooBar, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid object name 'qwerr7i623487er'.
```

So i to run a check to ensure that all stored procedures in the database are valid.

### Like sp_refreshview but for procedures

SQL Server does have the function `sp_refreshView`:

```
EXECUTE sp_refreshView 'Customers';
```

and it will validate the view. And we can extend it to validate **all** views in the database:

**RefreshAllViews**

```
DECLARE abc CURSOR FOR
     SELECT Table_Schema AS ViewSchema, TABLE_NAME AS ViewName
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
     ORDER BY newid()
OPEN abc

DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(128);
DECLARE @ViewName varchar(128);
--DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)

-- Build select string once 
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(2048)
--SET @SQLString = N'EXECUTE sp_RefreshView @View'
--SET @ParmDefinition = N'@View nvarchar(128)'

FETCH NEXT FROM abc 
INTO @SchemaName, @ViewName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = 'EXECUTE sp_RefreshView N'''+@SchemaName+'.'+@ViewName+'''';
    PRINT @SQLString
    EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQLString--, @ParmDefinition, @View = @ViewName

    FETCH NEXT FROM abc
    INTO @SchemaName, @ViewName
END
CLOSE abc
DEALLOCATE abc
```

### But there's no equivalent to validate stored procedures.

Comment: Please watch your tagging.  This was the _only_ question on the site tagged 'sqlserver'.  Use 'sql-server' instead.

Comment: Your proposed procedure is considering as "successfully marked for recompilation" some procedures pointing to fields that have been renamed.

Comment: @SergioPrats Yes. For the alternative, i have application code that i) gets the stored procedure definition pieces from sql server ii) assembles the full `CREATE PROCEDURE` sql iii) sets no_exec on iv) attempts to alter the stored procedure. The database will given an error v) the app catches the error and shows a unit-test failure.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this "in-place" - without getting all the create statements.

In addition to setting `NOEXEC ON`, you will also need to set your favorite `SHOWPLAN_* ON` (I use `SHOWPLAN_TEXT`).  Now you can get rid of your step 2 and just execute each procedure you retrieved in step 1.

Here is a sample using an individual stored procedure.  You can work it into your favorite loop:

```
create procedure tests @bob int as 
select * from missing_table_or_view
go 

set showplan_text on; 
go 

set noexec on 

exec tests 

set noexec off
go 
set showplan_text off; 
go 
drop procedure tests 
go
```

The above sample should generate the following output:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tests, Line 2
>   Invalid object name 'missing_table_or_view'.

Comment: Is there a reason why to `set showplan_text on;` but then `set showplan_XML off;` instead of `set showplan_text off;` ?

Comment: just a typo in this 10-year old answer.  corrected to `set showplan_text off;`

Answer (score 5):

The check suggested by KenJ is definitely the best one, since the recreate/alter-approaches does not find all errors. E.g.

- impossible execution plans due to query-hints
- I even had an SP referencing a non-existing table that went through without the error being detected.

Please find my version that checks all existing SPs at once with KenJ's method below. AFAIK, it will detect every error that will keep the SP from being executed.

```
--Forces the creation of execution-plans for all sps.
--To achieve this, a temporary SP is created that calls all existing SPs.
--It seems like the simulation of the parameters is not necessary. That makes things a lot easier.
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE PROCEDURE pTempCompileTest AS ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
SELECT @stmt = @stmt + 'EXEC [' + schemas.name + '].[' + procedures.name + '];'
    FROM sys.procedures
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON schemas.schema_id = procedures.schema_id
    WHERE schemas.name = 'dbo'
    ORDER BY procedures.name

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
GO

--Here, the real magic happens.
--In order to display as many errors as possible, XACT_ABORT is turned off.
--Unfortunately, for some errors, the execution stops anyway.
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
GO
--Showplan disables the actual execution, but forces t-sql to create execution-plans for every statement.
--This is the core of the whole thing!
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
GO
--You cannot use dynamic SQL in here, since sp_executesql will not be executed, but only show the string passed in in the execution-plan
EXEC pTempCompileTest
GO
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL OFF
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
--drop temp sp again
DROP PROCEDURE pTempCompileTest
--If you have any errors in the messages-window now, you should fix these...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sql 2008 r2 or below then do not use

SET NOEXEC ON

It only checks the syntax and  not for potential errors like the existence of tables or columns. 
Instead use:

SET FMTONLY ON

it will do a full compile as it tries to return the meta data of the stored procedure.

For 2012 and you will need to use stored procedure:
sp_describe_first_result_set

Also you can do a complete script in Tsql that checks all sp and views, its just a bit of work.

UPDATE
I wrote a complete solution for in tsql that goes through all user defined stored proceedures and checks there syntax. the script is long winded but can be found here http://chocosmith.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/tsql-recompile-all-views-and-stored-proceedures-and-check-for-error/

Comment: Has anyone tried `SET FMTONLY ON` (or `sp_describe_first_result_set`) with `TRUNCATE TABLE CustomerAccounts` ?

Comment: @ChocoSmith For **stored procedures**, is there a drawback of using sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule?  I've found that it will catch stored procedures that don't line up with tables or schema changes.

Comment: @Question3CPO Excellent catch/point, fmtonly will check the underlying schema but sp_refreshsqlmodule will check the current schema. sp_refreshsqlmodule will also work against views (its the same as calling sp_refreshview on views). sp_refreshsqlmodule is a bit slower but I don't think speed should be of concern when it comes to broken stored proceedures :).
I'll check it tonight and see if the update breaks anything.

Comment: @ChocoSmith Thanks for the response.  Good to know for future reference.

Comment: @Ian Boyd bit of a delay but... you will not truncate the table if you have fmtonly on

Answer (score 1):

In addition you might want to consider using [Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/11/25/visual-studio-team-system-2008-database-edition-gdr-rtm.aspx) which, among other things, does a static verification of all stored procedures in the project on build, thus ensuring that all are consistent with the current schema.

Comment: That only works, i assume, if you're developing in Visual Studio, or against an SQL Server 2008 database?

Comment: @Ian yes it only works with visual studio as it will use a specific database project type (to be more precise you need VS Team System), but it works with Sql Server 2005 also

Answer (score 1):

I know this is way old, but I created a slightly different version that actually re-creates all stored procedures, thus throwing errors if they cannot compile. This is something you do not achieve by using the SP_Recompile command.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UTL_ForceSPRecompilation
(
    @Verbose BIT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN

    --Forces all stored procedures to recompile, thereby checking syntax validity.

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SPName NVARCHAR(255)           

    DECLARE abc CURSOR FOR
         SELECT NAME, OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.[object_id])
         FROM sys.objects AS o 
         WHERE o.[type] = 'P'
         ORDER BY o.[name]

    OPEN abc

    FETCH NEXT FROM abc
    INTO @SPName, @SQL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN       

        --This changes "CREATE PROCEDURE" to "ALTER PROCEDURE"
        SET @SQL = 'ALTER ' + RIGHT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - (CHARINDEX('CREATE', @SQL) + 6))

        IF @Verbose <> 0 PRINT @SPName

        EXEC(@SQL)

        FETCH NEXT FROM abc
        INTO @SPName, @SQL
    END
    CLOSE abc
    DEALLOCATE abc  

END
```

Comment: Works fine, but needs to handle `CREATE PROC` too

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but this is my solution when I could not find any suiting.

I required to validate my stored procedures and views after alot of changes in the database.

Basicly what i wanted was to try to do a ALTER PROCEDURE and ALTER VIEW using the current procedures and view (not actually changing them).

I have written this that works fairly well.

**Note! Do not perform on live database, make a copy to validate and then fix the things need fixing. Also sys.sql_modules can be inconsistent so take extra care. I do not use this to actually make the changes, only to check which are not working properly.**

```
DECLARE @scripts TABLE
(
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Command NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Type] NVARCHAR(1)
)

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX),        -- Name of procedure or view
    @command NVARCHAR(MAX),         -- Command or part of command stored in syscomments
    @type NVARCHAR(1)               -- Procedure or view

INSERT INTO @scripts(Name, Command, [Type])
SELECT P.name, M.definition, 'P' FROM sys.procedures P 
JOIN sys.sql_modules M ON P.object_id = M.object_id

INSERT INTO @scripts(Name, Command, [Type])
SELECT V.name, M.definition, 'V' FROM sys.views V 
JOIN sys.sql_modules M ON V.object_id = M.object_id

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name, Command, [Type]  FROM @scripts

OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @name, @command, @type


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        IF @type = 'P'
            SET @command = REPLACE(@command, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
        ELSE
            SET @command = REPLACE(@command, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW')


        EXEC sp_executesql @command
        PRINT @name + ' - OK'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT @name + ' - FAILED: ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
        --PRINT @command
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs
    INTO @name, @command, @type
END

CLOSE curs
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a drawn-out option:

1. Create a copy of the database
   (backup and restore). You could do this on the target database, if your confidence level is high.
2. Use SSMS to script out all the
   stored procedures into a single script file
3. DROP all the procedures
4. Run the script to recreate them. Any that can't be created will error out.

Couple of fussy gotchas in here, such as:

- You want to have the "if proc exists
  then drop proc GO create proc ... GO"
  syntax to separte each procedure.
- Nested procedures will fail if they
  call a proc that has not yet been
  (re)created. Running the script several
  times should catch that (since
  ordering them properly can be a real
  pain).
- Other and more obscure issues might crop up, so be wary.

To quickly drop 10 or 1000 procedures, run

```
SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + schema_name(schema_id) + '.' +  name
 from sys.procedures
```

select the output, and run it.

This assumes you're doing a very infrequent task. If you have to do this regularly (daily, weekly...), please let us know why!

Comment: Yeah - no way i'm dropping stored procedures on the live database ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it from T-SQL, or Enterprise Manager, so i had to write something from client code. i won't post all the code here, but the trick is to:

1) Get a list of all stored procedures

```
 SELECT ROUTINE_NAME AS StoredProcedureName
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
 WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' --as opposed to a function
 ORDER BY ROUTINE_NAME
```

2) Get the stored procedure create T-SQL:

```
select
   c.text
from dbo.syscomments c
where c.id = object_id(N'StoredProcedureName')
order by c.number, c.colid
option(robust plan)
```

3) Run the create statement with NOEXEC on, so that the syntax is checked, but it doesn't actually try to create the stored procedure:

```
connection("SET NOEXEC ON", ExecuteNoRecords);
connection(StoredProcedureCreateSQL, ExecuteNoRecords);
connection("SET NOEXEC ON", ExecuteNoRecords);
```

Comment: Decided to accept your challenge :D 
not sure if we are allowed to self plug blogs but I posted the complete solution on my blog. It turned out to be quiet long.
[link](http://chocosmith.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/tsql-recompile-all-views-and-stored-proceedures-and-check-for-error/)
I haven't checked against truncate table though but i can see it being an problem. 
I don't think management studio gets that correct either though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an amendment which deals with multiple schemas

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RefreshAllViews] AS

-- This sp will refresh all views in the catalog. 
--     It enumerates all views, and runs sp_refreshview for each of them

DECLARE abc CURSOR FOR
     SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+TABLE_NAME AS ViewName
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
OPEN abc

DECLARE @ViewName varchar(128)

-- Build select string
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(2048)

FETCH NEXT FROM abc 
INTO @ViewName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = 'EXECUTE sp_RefreshView ['+@ViewName+']'
    PRINT @SQLString
    EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSQL @SQLString

    FETCH NEXT FROM abc
    INTO @ViewName
END
CLOSE abc
DEALLOCATE abc
GO
```