# Determine errors in stored procedures if table design changes

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is more a hypothetical question, but suppose if someone makes a table change within SQL Server that breaks a Stored Procedure - or a large number of Stored Procedures, is there a way to determine what is broken?

Suppose I have a stored procedure which returns some user data

```
SELECT user.Id,
       user.FirstName,
       user.LastName
FROM Users
```

Then a developer makes a change to the table and changes LastName column name to Surname.  But he forgets to change the related stored procedures.

I can use SQL Server to see the dependencies of a stored procedure, but I want to know which stored procedures are just broken.

Or in my case, if I have stored procedures that reference 3rd Party tables and the 3rd Party totally revamps their tables.

Is there any way to check?

Comment: script out all SPs as alter, then run it and see where it errors :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use schema binding on views, functions, and in versions 14 and up stored procedures as well.  This would be a proactive way to prevent a developer from making a change that would break a view, function, or procedure.

Otherwise you'll have to use a script to check.  I think this question has some information that could help you:
[Syntax check all stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177659/syntax-check-all-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 1):

For procedures, you can use this cursor:

```
Declare list_cursor Cursor 
For
Select code = 'sp_refreshsqlmodule '''+OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(object_id)+'''' From sys.procedures
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Open list_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM list_cursor INTO @sql

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    Begin Try
        Exec sp_executesql @sql
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        print @sql
        print '   '+ERROR_MESSAGE()
    End Catch
    FETCH NEXT FROM list_cursor INTO @sql
END

CLOSE list_cursor
DEALLOCATE list_cursor
```